# VS2008 How I can get rid of the "Error List" window

Tags: visual-studio-2008, list, window

I don't really like the Error list window, I prefer to use the Output window.
The only way I can hide the Error list window is to make it floating and to put it as a small popup window in a window corner
Thanks!

-Claudio

Comment: can't you close it? click the `'X'` button..

Comment: Visual Studio will show it again when you build the solution/project.

Comment: Reminds me of the famous compiler message "Too many errors. Make less."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck the option to popup the error list each time that the build ends with errors at `Tools\Options\Project and Solutions\General` "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors" and the error list will stop popping up.

Comment: Thanx, there are so many options in tools that I didn't see it before!

Answer (score 0):

In tools > options > projects and solutions > general

uncheck Always show error list if build finishes with errors.

Kindness,

Dan